# Guice constructor injection of String dependency (or other unbound primitive)?

Tags: java, constructor, dependency-injection, guice

Here is some code:

```
public class InjectedClass{
    private final Dependency dependency;
    private final String string;
    @Inject 
    public InjectedClass(Dependency dependency, String string){
        this.dependency=dependency;
        this.string=string;
    }
 }
```

Let's say that I have bound my dependency in my module, but I do not have any binding for a String there. How/what does Guice choose to be a default for the String argument? In my (more complicated) test case, it seems to be setting it to "", however the logic for how it does that is not apparent to me and I do not know if this is deterministic behavior.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By default Guice will instantiate any object that has either

- An @Inject-marked non-private constructor
- A non-private no-args constructor
- A default constructor (no constructor)

Because String has a no-args public constructor, new String() will create a string equivalent to `""`

This is deterministic behavior, and will happen with any type that has the above conditions.  If you are concerned about it, you can do

```
binder().requireAtInjectOnConstructors()
```

then Guice will simply report a missing binding.  Additionally there is a future enhancement being planned which will prevent java.lang.* types from being bound without a qualifier/bindingannotation.  This would also prevent core types like String or Integer from being automatically bound with "" or 0 just because someone injected them.

Answer (score -1):

The [docs](https://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/Injections) mentions

```
@Inject(optional=true)
```

Which will enable guice to use default values.

"Mixing optional injection and just-in-time bindings may yield surprising results. For example, the following field is always injected even when Date is not explicitly bound. This is because Date has a public no-arguments constructor that is eligible for just-in-time bindings."

Strings likely behave the same way as a Date does in the document example where it simply calls the default no-argument constructor.

Comment: @Inject(optional=true) is something that we are gradually going to be eliminating in Guice, in favor of DefaultBinding and OptionalBinding (new in 4.0).  This is not really an answer to the issue in the qeustion though.